Why did my Linux SSD start to have significantly slow write speed? What can be done to improve the write speed?
Recently my Arch Linux SSD (a 1TB Crucial BX500) started slowing down causing the system to be unresponsive and freezing at times. After running a quick benchmark it showed that the read speeds were normal (around 500MB/s as expected) but the write speeds were significantly lower than expected (around 30MB/s).
I also ran a SMART test on the drive and showed a 79% lifetime which compared to the Windows SSD I have (same model and time of use) is very low.
At this point, I'm starting to think the Linux SSD is probably leaving this ugly world and that I should change it. Although, there's something I did which made things better: I formatted and recreated the Linux boot partition from scratch and things were suddenly back to normal… but with some catches. I reran the KDiskMark benchmarks and they were kind of flaky but, in general, much better than before and the system was now more fluid.
Is there anything else I should try, before definitely swapping out the SSD?
SMART test on bad drive:

SMART test on good drive:


I'm not familiar with Arch Linux, but maybe this answer will lead you somewhere useful: SSD Trim on Archlinux.

What is your VM.swappiness set to? If its set to 60 (which seems to be a default) setting it to a lower value - say 5 - could make the system a lot more interactive if you are using memory heavily (like lots of browser tags). Its not a panacea though.

I already have set up a systemd unit which TRIMs the SSD weekly

Looking at the specs at https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/crucial-bx500-ssd,5377.html I came across this - "Crucial’s BX500 provides up to 540/500 MB/s of sequential read/write throughput, but that can drop to an average of just 100 MB/s during a sustained workload."  and digging further (for the 240GB version of the drive) a random transfer of 68 MB/sec- so a the problem may be the design of the drive - My guess is you are seeing a drive with a slow  write speed for large volumes of data coupled with a lot of swapping.  I don't think the drive is failing but it is entry level tech.

Given that Arch Linux, iirc, does not do any Trim of any kind by default and this sounds very strongly like a drive that hasn't been Trim-ed... I strongly suspect that is the issue here. More info here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Solid_state_drive

The drive appears to be fine — as in "performing as designed" — however it is not designed to perform well when writing.
This is an entry level drive, and the write speeds are underwhelming — see https://tomshardware.com/reviews/crucial-bx500-ssd,5377.html — which found figures of 68-100 megabytes per second for sustained writes.
The 79% figure (which seams a bit suspect to me - the math does not add up ) means that the drive has written about 21% of what it could be expected to write over its lifespan.   As you have only written 11TB to date to the drive that would not seem an issue. The reason I think this 79% figure is suspect is because the drive is a 1TB drive with an endurance of 360TB. It would seem that the endurance figure is calculated as if the drive was only the 250GB model.
It might be an idea to see what your drive IO looks like — I suspect that there is a lot of swapping going on.   First thing to look at for swap is how much is in use.  You can do this with
  free -h

If you have a significant amount of swap enabled, you can look at used and free to get a feel for how heavily used swap is, but this is somewhat inaccurate and crude.
You can get a better feel for IO by running a command like:
 vmstat 5

And looking at the swap and IO columns.  This will show you the instantaneous amount of swap being used. If swap is high you can either add more RAM to your system or change the swappiness to a low value (or both). I've not used arch, but generally you can change this by editing /etc/sysctl.conf and adding/changing the line:
 vm.swappiness = 5

Then run:
 sysctl -p  

To load it into the current running system.
Of course, a new drive with a better controller will likely give you much better performance than you can get from the current drive. If your system supports NVMe drives, they will leave SATA for dead — but even a SATA drive with a good controller will give 5-10 times your current level of write performance.

If the drive has never been properly trimmed (not sure if Arch enables periodic fstrim by default or not, or if the OP may have that turned off), I would not be hugely surprised by a quote of 21% used endurance with only 11TB written. The full lifetime write endurance numbers generally assume that proper maintenance, including periodic trimming of free space, is done.

@DavidECarella wrote a rejected edit which is interesting and should be a comment - He wrote Note: 11TB is the Total Host Writes which looks better than 15TB, but the much higher Average Block Erase Count (0xD3 = 211 vs 0x1C = 28) is consistent with Lifetime Remaining and suggests worse write amplification. Other SMART values not shown might help paint a more complete picture. Performing ATA Secure Erase should restore the drive to fresh out-of-box (FOB) state.    (I do not agree with the "fresh out the box" statement, but the statement is noteworthy and could imply issues with TRIM as well)
